# Django Openshift Page error

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have a project that I'm working on, the pages work fine when I run the server locally but when I upload the project to openshift the only page that display's is the home page at -
http://python.apps.devcloud.****.****.**.**/

When I try to view another page like http://python.apps.devcloud.****.****.**.**/api/team I get a server error however when I view this locally at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/team/ the page works!

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from django.contrib import admin
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#makes sure that the API endpoints work
router.register(r'api/team', views.TeamViewSet)
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'marine.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)
```

Logs added:

```
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 95957 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3170 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1832 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 36816 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 13632 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1760 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:54 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/img/grid.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1458 "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:59 +0100] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 78 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:59 +0100] "GET /api/team HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:52:59 +0100] "GET /api/team/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4814 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/prettify.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:31 +0100] "GET /static/rest_framework/img/grid.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://mydomain.apps.devcloud.co.uk/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:36 +0100] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 78 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
***.***.**.*** - - [28/Mar/2016:19:54:45 +0100] "GET /api/team/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: You should tell us what the error actually is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It just shows Server Error 500

Comment: But what do the logs say?

Comment: @DanielRoseman how do I check logs?

Comment: Haven't used openshift much, but a quick Google shows this: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, added the logs